# how to get trashed with eloquent model using where and with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have users model in laravel

```
public static function searchScoop($keyword)        
{
    $users = User::where('username','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->

    orwhere('email','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->

    orwhere('phone','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->

    with('user_permission','user_division')->

    get(['id','username','email','phone','division','permission']);

    return $users;
}
```

now how can i get trashed results with users variable 
i tried to to put withTrashed -> before where after get everywhere but noting works ..

thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try with  `withTrashed()` which will give also the soft deleted records. If you only want soft deleted records use `onlyTrashed()`

```
 public static function searchScoop($keyword)
    {
        $users = User::withTrashed()
        ->where('username','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orwhere('email','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orwhere('phone','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->with('user_permission','user_division')
        ->get(['id','username','email','phone','division','permission']);
        return $users;
    }
```

Comment: OP mentioned `withTrashed->` , which is not the correct usage, the correct one is `withTrashed()` . Anyway thanks for mentioning `deleted_at` field

Comment: Incase you wanted to return only the trashed you may use  `onlyTrashed()`.

Comment: As @Onensimon suggested, `withTrashed` will also return the *not soft deleted* records.

Answer (score 2):

This is [correct syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models):

```
public static function searchScoop($keyword)
{
    return User::withTrashed()
        ->where('username', 'like' ,'%'.$keyword.'%')->
        ->orwhere('email', 'like' ,'%'.$keyword.'%')->
        ->orwhere('phone', 'like' ,'%'.$keyword.'%')->
        ->with('user_permission', 'user_division')->
        ->get(['id', 'username', 'email', 'phone', 'division', 'permission']);
}
```

Comment: All the `withTrashed()` method does is remove the scope that adds the "deleted_at is null" condition to the query. Adding the `deleted_at` column to the select list wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @patricus I've just tested it and you're right. Thanks for noticing.